# Сохранение файлов в папку

Tags: php

У меня есть код на php, суть его - сохранить файл в папку

```
function save_source_code($cName, $cData)
{
    $cache = fopen("source/" . $cName . ".tmp", "w+");
    fwrite($cache, $cData);
    fclose($cache);
}

function get_source_code($cName)
{
    return @file_get_contents("source/" . $cName . ".tmp");
}

function clear_source_code($cName, $tClean)
{
    $cTime = filemtime("source/" . $cName . ".tmp");
    $cLive = (time() - $cTime) / 3600;

    if ($cLive >= $tClean) {
        unlink("source/" . $cName . ".tmp");
    }
}
```

Вызываю его так. Пример:

```
$mCode = get_source_code ( md5($_GET['id']) );
```

Все работает, но в папку isp manager не сохраняет больше 100 000 файлов. Я хочу, чтобы  после папки `/source/`, создавалась ещё подпапка с названием первого символа `.$cName`.
Чтобы все файлы были не в одной папке, а в разных. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 3):

```
function creat_dir($cName){
   $dir=substr($cName, 0, 1);
   if(!is_dir("source/".$dir)){
      if(mkdir("source/".$dir, 0777)){
         return $dir;
      } else return false;
   } else return $dir;
}
```

И перепишем вашу функцию save_source_code():

```
function save_source_code($cName,$cData) {
   $dir=creat_dir($cName);
   if($dir){
       $cache = fopen("source/".$dir."/".$cName.".tmp", "w+");
       fwrite($cache, $cData);
       fclose($cache);
   }
}
```

Comment: function creat_dir($cName)
почемуто не работает какае то ошибка вообще php файл незапускается ,
немогу понять в чем дело

Comment: Ну так ошибку покажите, или гадать сидеть?

Comment: я незнаю просто не выполняется файл php ошибка 500 сервер неотвечает 
я незнаю как ошибку вывести в  php
но знаю точно папку 
скажем 
mkdir("source/e", 0777); создать может вне функции

Comment: Обратитесь к хостеру. функция правильная,я  проверил, у меня работает.

Comment: Спасибо за код всё работает нехватало одной скобки
вместо if(!is_dir("source/".$dir){надо
if(!is_dir("source/".$dir)){ но это просто апечатка .